# Change datatables ScrollY clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables-1.10

I have a dataTable like this one:

[image]

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <?php 
        $query = "SELECT something";
        $get_result = sqlsrv_query($conection,$query);
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_result)){ 
          $dest = $row['dest'];
          $num1 = $row['num1'];
          $num2 = $row['num2'];
          $num3 = $row['num3'];
          echo "<tr>
                  <td class='hidden'>{$dest}</td>
                  <td>{$num1}</td>
                  <td>{$num2}</td>
                  <td>{$num3}</td>                                
               </tr>";
         }
         sqlsrv_close($conection);
         ?>  
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <div class="the_button">
    <a href="#" id="view_all_link" class="button">View All</a>                
 </div>
```

And my js for the dataTable :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY":        "100px", // Here
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging":         false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([0]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value="">Select Option</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    ); 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
} );
```

} );

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

So lets go in my problem.

I want when the **button view all is clicked** to change the `ScrollY` from **100px to `auto` value or 500px** e.g.

I tried many examples found on community but not chance.

I tried by changing the css with js but not luck.

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 400); Not working for me this one
```

Also I tried to leave the **ScrollY** blank and add the `height` with `CSS` and `javascript` but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced a similar problem, but this was my solution:

```
   $("#myTable").DataTable({scrollY: 100}); 
   // ...
   $("#myTable").DataTable({retrieve: true}).destroy();
   // ...
   $("#myTable").DataTable({scrollY: 200});
```

I did this because dataTables are intended to run with a single initialisation. The retrieve option on the second executable line above only returns the instance without re-initialisation the dataTable, then I call destroy on it - which reverts all the changes the plugin has made to the DOM. a Simple re-initialisation was the dirty fix that changed the height as per required.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and is explained in the datatables documentation: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: So @Eon if I get this right. Should run my table like I am doing and call a onclick function and destroy the table on call and apply the new scroll?

Comment: @Maria That would be the intention yes. if you want to check if your table had been destroyed, you can always call `$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#myTable")`. It also doesn't Destroy the ENTIRE table, but just the injected dataTables DOM (the html that datatables added)

Comment: a pleasure, @maria